# Setting CSS for relative element

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery so go easy on me.

Using the following HTML:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td headers="QTY">
   <input type="hidden" name="f50" value="1">
  </td>
  <td headers="COLOR">
   <input type="text" name="f01">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td headers="QTY">
   <input type="hidden" name="f50" value="0">
  </td>
  <td headers="COLOR">
   <input type="text" name="f01">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to do the following:

1. For each row
2. look at the value of the hidden item "f50"
3. If the value = 1 then set the background color of f01 to green for the same row
4. If the value != 1 then set the background color of f01 to yellow for the same row

So far, I have this:

```
$('input[name="f50"]').each
(
 function(index)
 {
  var theItem = this;

  if (parseInt(theItem.value) == 1)
  {
   alert ('Make Green');
  }
  else
  {
    alert ('Make Yellow');
  }
 }
);
```

I am not sure how I reference the relative f01 element from where I am.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Duncs

Comment: It is an array holding many values. ID should be unique, name can be used for multiple items in say a tabular form.

Comment: better to use class="f50" as well, and let jQuery work on the classes.

Comment: ok but my original questions still remains :)

Comment: @RononDex The `name` attribute does not have to be unique. For instance, radio button inputs will share a `name` in order to act like, well, radio buttons. [Example](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics#Step_three:_Adding_some_more_complex_form_elements) from W3C wiki.

Comment: @ajp15243 Nice point, didn't knew that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they're in the same tr, you can use `closest('tr')` to find the parent tr, and `find` on this tr to get the wanted element.

```
var closestf01 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="f01"]');
```

then

```
closestf01.css('background-color', 'yellow'); // or green
```

so

```
$('input[name="f50"]').each(function(index) {
  var f01 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="f01"]');
  if ($(this).val() == 1)//or this.value == 1
      f01.css('background-color', 'yellow');

  else
      f01.css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

or "shorter"

```
$('input[name="f50"]').each(function(index) {
      $(this)
            .closest('tr')
            .find('input[name="f01"]')
            .css('background-color', (this.value == 1 ? 'yellow' : 'green'));
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufQ3r/1)

Comment: Awesome. Cheers for that. Seems simple once you have a worked example. Many thanks. Duncs

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input[name="f50"]').each(function() {
  var  this_val = $(this).val();

    if (this_val == 1) {
        alert("Make Green");
        $(this).addClass('green'); 
    } else { 
        alert('Make Yellow'); 
        $(this).addClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/txw66/2/

Comment: Also you should use the keyword `var` to declare variables: `var this_name = ...`

Comment: `this_name` doesn't seem to be used. It is also best to explain code in your answers, so that the OP can learn.

Comment: I'll give this a go to see if it works as well. Thanks for taking the time to respond. As I said above. It's really helpful to see a working example. Cheers, Duncs

Comment: thanks for correction, i wrote my code just as an idea so made a little mistake here. you can check live working fiddle now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[name="f50"]').each
(
 function(index)
 {
  var theItem = this;

  if (parseInt(theItem.value) == 1)
  {
   $(theItem).parent().next().find('input[name="f01"]').css('background-color','green');
  }
  else
  {
    $(theItem).parent().next().find('input[name="f01"]').css('background-color','yellow');
  }
 }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HFV9N/

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$('[name="f50"][value="1"]').closest('tr').find('[name="f01"]').css('background-color','green');
$('[name="f50"]:not([value="1"])').closest('tr').find('[name="f01"]').css('background-color','yellow');
```

As stated by @RononDex, the name property should be unique - a global selecter using this property isn't guaranteed to work in all browsers. You should consider using `data-blahblah` attributes instead, like `<input type="hidden" data-which="f50" value="1" />`.